# How to create a table using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I've the dictionary in inside the tag and I wanted to create the table from it. Here is the xml file I've

```
<parent>
  <thread thread_id="5e778ef9a28f9a51fec330b4">
    {'relative_to_thread_interactors': 1.0, 'relative_to_self_threads': 1.0}
  </thread>
  <thread thread_id="5e778ef9a28f2b51fec330A3">
    {'relative_to_thread_interactors': 2.0, 'relative_to_self_threads': 1.0}
  </thread> 
</parent>
```

And here is my xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent/thread">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@thread_id"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="thread"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now my question is how to create a table from the dictionary value?

```
| thread_id                | relative_to_thread_interactors |
|--------------------------|--------------------------------|
| 5e778ef9a28f2b51fec330A3 | 2.0                            |
```

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="/parent">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>thread_id</th>
            <th>relative_to_thread_interactors</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="thread">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@thread_id"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select='substring-before(substring-after(., "&apos;relative_to_thread_interactors&apos;: "), ",")'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

---

In XSLT 2.0 it could be more elegant by using regex.

Comment: Hey that works. Found this `substring-before(haystack ,needle )` in mozilla doc  

Comment: Hi Michael. Is it possible to print all the keys in that dictionary. ?